# A conjecture about primorials

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, primorial

A primorial, denoted $p_n\#$, is the product of the first $n$ prime numbers ($p_1=2,\ p_2=3$ etc.). The magnitude of primorials grows rapidly beyond the range of convenient arithmetic manipulation.  The number $(p_n\#+1)$ is not divisible by any of the first $n$ primes, and so is frequently a prime number itself. For $n=1,2,3,4,5,11$, $(p_n\#+1) \in \mathbb P$.

I noticed (for primorials accessible to calculation) that when $(p_n\#+1) \not \in \mathbb P$, that a 'near primorial' number plus $1$ could be identified that was a prime. By near primorial number, I mean the product of all but one of the first $n$ primes, or $\frac{p_n\#}{p_i};\ 1<i<n$. For example, $\frac{p_8\#}{3}+1,\ \frac{p_{10}\#}{3}+1,\ \frac{p_6\#}{5}+1,\ \frac{p_7\#}{5}+1,\ \frac{p_{12}\#}{7}+1,\ \frac{p_{13}\#}{11}+1,\ \frac{p_{9}\#}{13}+1$ are all primes. Examples of this kind can be rewritten in the form $p_n\#=p_i(p_k-1);\ 1<i<n,\ k>n$.

Based on this admittedly extremely small set, I conjecture that it might be the case $$p_n\#=C(p_k-1);\ C\in \{1,p_i\},\ 1<i<n,\ k>n$$ The signal feature of $C$ is that it is not composite. A single counterexample arrived at by computation would disprove the conjecture, but for $p_{14}\#$ and greater, the numbers are beyond my ability to conveniently calculate.

**My questions are**: Has this conjecture been previously considered and settled? If not, is there an analytic approach to prove or disprove the conjecture?

Comment: I think you have some mistakes. Possibly they are just typos. For example: $p_9=23$. $(p_9\#/5)+1=44618575$, which is clearly not prime. I think your last three example primes are, in fact, composite. Their smallest prime factors are $5; 2861; 103$ respectively.

Comment: @nickgard Thanks for the check. Not a simple typo, but a slipped index in the calculations. I've rechecked and edited the post. I think the examples are all correct now, but in any event the conjecture wasn't invalidated up to this point.

Comment: Your statement of the conjecture is not correct.  As I read the text, the conjecture would be that if $p_n\#+1$ is not prime, there is some $p_i$ with $i \lt n$ such that $\frac {p_n\#}{p_i}+1$ is prime.

Comment: @Ross Millikan Your statement of the conjecture is  correct, but I fail to see how it differs from my statement. If $\frac{p_n\#}{C}+1=p_k$, then either $C=1$ and $p_n\# = 1\cdot (p_k-1)$, or $C=p_i$ and $p_n\# = p_i\cdot (p_k-1)$. Unless I messed up notation somehow (always a possibility), I think that's what I said.

Comment: No, you are correct, they are equivalent.

Comment: @reuns The probability that $N$ is prime is $\approx \frac{1}{ln N}$ if $N$ is a randomly chosen number. But in this instance, $N$ is chosen to have essentially no small prime factors, a decidedly non-random property.

Comment: The point Ross is making is that if your conjecture were true, you would have very cheap algorithm for generating primes. Which, for whatever definition of cheap you want, is either proven not to exists or highly unlikely to exist. As a side note, you might want to consider python for numerical experiments of this type involving big numbers. I'm sure you'll find a counter example soon.

Comment: @prosinac The OP didn't provide any easy way to check if $p_n\# / C+1$ is prime. Finding very large primes is not hard, proving they are is.

Comment: For $p_{19}\# = 7858321551080267055879090$, the conjecture is not satisfied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few lines of Mathematica shows that $p_{19}\#$ is the first counterexample. $$p_{19}\# = \bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{19}p_i\bigg)+1=7858321551080267055879091=54730729297\cdot 143581524529603,$$ so it is composite. The following table shows that $\frac{p_{19}\#}{p_n}+1$ is composite for all $n$ satisfying $1\leq n < 19$
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
 n & p_n & \frac{p_{19}\#}{p_n}+1 & \text{smallest divisor of }\frac{p_{19}\#}{p_n}+1\\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3929160775540133527939546 & 2 \\ \hline
2 & 3 & 2619440517026755685293031 & 613 \\ \hline
3 & 5 & 1571664310216053411175819 & 5501 \\ \hline
4 & 7 & 1122617364440038150839871 & 21713 \\ \hline
5 & 11 & 714392868280024277807191 & 389 \\ \hline
6 & 13 & 604486273160020542759931 & 131 \\ \hline
7 & 17 & 462254208887074532698771 & 101 \\ \hline
8 & 19 & 413595871109487739783111 & 136483 \\ \hline
9 & 23 & 341666154394794219820831 & 26801 \\ \hline
10 & 29 & 270976605209664381237211 & 809 \\ \hline
11 & 31 & 253494243583234421157391 & 127 \\ \hline
12 & 37 & 212387068948115325834571 & 3449 \\ \hline
13 & 41 & 191666379294640659899491 & 3593 \\ \hline
14 & 43 & 182751663978610861764631 & 167 \\ \hline
15 & 47 & 167198330874048235231471 & 71 \\ \hline
16 & 53 & 148270217944910699167531 & 2866463 \\ \hline
17 & 59 & 133191890696275712811511 & 283 \\ \hline
18 & 61 & 128824943460332246817691 & 179 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

What says the random model :

Let $j\le n$ and $$f(j,n) = 1+\prod_{i=1, i \ne j}^n p_i$$

By Mertens theorem $\log f(j,n) \approx \sum_{i=1}^n \log p_i \approx n$

Assuming independence of the congruences $\bmod$ different primes
$$Pr(f(j,n) \text{ is prime}] \approx \frac{\prod_{i \ne j} (1-p_i)^{-1}}{\ln N} \ge C\exp(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{p_i} - \ln \ln N)\\ \approx C \exp( \ln \ln (n-1) - \ln n) \approx C\frac{\ln n}{n}$$

Taking $j $ uniformly in $1\ldots n$, assuming the random variables "$f(j,n)$ is prime" are independent,

the probability that none of the $f(j,n)$ is prime is $$\approx \prod_{j=1}^n (1-C\frac{\ln n}{n})= (1-C\frac{\ln n}{n})^n = \exp(n\log (1-C\frac{\ln n}{n})) \approx \exp(-C \ln n)) = n^{-C}$$

If you redo it replacing $j$ by a subset $J \subset 1 \ldots n$ with $4$ elements and $f(j,n)$ by $f(J,n) = 1+\prod_{i=1, i \not \in J} p_i$ you'll get $C > 1$ so that the probability that for some $n \ge N$, none of the $f(J,n)$ is prime is $\le \sum_{n=N}^\infty n^{-C}$ which $\to 0$ as $N \to \infty$,

ie. it is almost surely true that for every $n$ large enough $p_n\# = a_n (p_{k_n}-1)$ with $a_n$ a product of at most $4$ primes.