# Primorial Primes (Euclid primes): do they become more scarce?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, primorial

I remember from my first number theory class a woman asking if every number that is the product of all primes plus one is prime. I know that this is false. I also know that at first it looks like it might be true. What I wonder is, do we know anything about the distribution: are most candidates indeed prime? Are there gaps where 2 or more candidates in a row are not prime?

A related question that maybe I should ask separately but I will first try here: in cases where the candidate is not prime, does there: 1. tend to be a prime nearby? 2. Can a prime always be generated by taking out one of the primes from the sequence (not the last one)?

Comment: No one even knows if there are infinitely many such primes.  As to nearby primes, well $p_1\times \cdots \times p_n\pm p_i$ is clearly divisible by $p_i$ so, depending on what "nearby" means, no.

Comment: I know that we do not know if there are an infinite but I am asking about distribution: how common "exceptions" are. There is the long initial stretch or all primes; i wonder if there are similar stretches later on, also or there are long composite stretches.

Comment: For information relevant to your second question, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3288074/a-conjecture-about-primorials

Comment: Heuristics indicate infinite many such primes. What makes the chance good for them to be prime that a primorial cannot have small prime factors because of their construction. Nevertheless, it becomes more and more difficult to find an even larger such prime.

Comment: If $p$#$+1$ is not prime, the gap must exceed $p$ and I think, it can be much larger. But $p$#$+q$ with primes $p<q$ has good chances to be prime if $p$ is not too large. With a reasonable input $p$ we can probably find such a prime with reasonable effort.

Comment: In wikipedia you can find the primorial primes upto a very large limit.

Comment: Concerning large primes with variations of this approach : Noone knows a way to construct huge numbers that have a very good chance to be prime, otherwise, a new record prime would occur much more frequently. Even for small candidates, we have nothing better than trial division (algebraic factors or similar ones are very unlikely) and a primality test (maybe only a probable-prime-test)

Answer (score -2):

You wrote in a comment that you’re aware that we don’t know whether infinitely many Euclid numbers are prime, and indeed your questions might be answered without knowing this. But we also don’t know whether infinitely many Euclid numbers are composite – at least we didn’t in $1996$, see [The New Book of Prime Number Records](https://books.google.de/books?id=2VTSBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PR2&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Paulo Ribenboim, and [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimorialPrime.html) still gives this as the current state of the question.

Together, these known unknowns imply that the answers to your questions are unknown. If we knew that most Euclid numbers are prime, we’d know that infinitely many are prime, and if we knew that it’s not the case that most are prime, we’d know that infinitely many are composite. If we knew that infinitely many pairs of successive Euclid numbers are composite, we’d know that infinitely many are composite, and if we knew that this isn’t the case, we’d know that infinitely many are prime.